# Unable to open an Excel file created using <CFSavecontent> in office 365

Tags: coldfusion

I have several spreadsheets that are being generated using `<cfsaveContent>`. All this while it worked fine, but now that we are moved to office365, those files .XLS cannot be opened anymore. Does someone know of a utility or API to which I can pass the generated file and convert it to a valid Excel format?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How are you creating these files and what error occurs when opening them? Without knowing more, it sounds like you are actually generating something Excel can interpret i.e. HTML, not a true binary Excel file. Older versions of Excel *used to* open HTML files without issue. However, newer versions have increased security features which may trigger warnings or reject the file altogether. If that is the issue, better to generate a "real" Excel file as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a utility to convert existing files, but you'll want to start using either cfspreadsheet if you're using ACF or use Apache POI via Java.

Answer (score 1):

We have experienced the same issue. It relates to a security patch in Excel. Make sure your HTML table containing the data in the CFSaveContent is valid html with thead, tbody, ect. That fixed it for us.